# How to publish an iOS App to crashlytics via jenkins?

Tags: ios, svn, jenkins

I have my Xcode pro on svn repository,
on archiving I can successfully upload and distribute my app through crashlytics, 
But now I wish to invoke jenkins to do unit testing after I update on svn and want jenkins to upload it to Crashlytics via  or some other way.

Comment: obviously i did google it but anyways thanks @dogsgod  
jenkins does not have any post Build option for directly uploading build to crashlytics as it has for testFlight and others.

Comment: ok i added post script  and its successfully uploading to crashlytics now 
/Users/*****/Desktop/JenkinsWorkspace/Crashlytics.framework/submit **API Key** **BuildSecret**d -ipaPath /Users/*****/Desktop/JenkinsWorkspace/Exported/TestJenkins.ipa -emails *****.com,*****.com -notesPath /Users/*****/Desktop/JenkinsWorkspace/ReleaseNotes.rtf -groupAliases TestGroup01 -notifications YES

Comment: अर्जुन, where did you put your jenkins post script? Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have automated the same, that is running the tests after which the build is uploaded to Crashlytics using a tool called Fastlane. It is pretty simple setting up by following the docs provided. You just have to include the fastlane commands in the shell while configuring the build steps of the job and also the api token and build secret as environment variables in Jenkins.

https://docs.fastlane.tools/